# Scaling image is slow compared to self made image scaler

Tags: android, imageview

So I'm using a view pager to display multiple fragments. Each fragment is containing multiple images. The images have to be displayed on the full width of the screen but the image also have to remain its aspect ratio. Firstly I thought I could do it like below, because the images are static:

```
<ImageView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:src="@drawable/image"
                android:contentDescription="@string/imageView_ride_height_overview_content_description"
                android:id="@+id/imageView_ride_height_overview"/>
```

However my viewpager became a little bit sluggish. So I started the hierarchy viewer and saw the image took around 50ms to draw. This is way too much to let my viewpager run smoothly.

I thought maybe the scaling of the image took way too long so I implemented my own image scaler it looks like this:

```
    Bitmap bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.image);
    Display display = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    int width = bitmapOrg.getWidth();
    int height = bitmapOrg.getHeight();
    float scale = (float) display.getWidth()/width;
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postScale(scale, scale);
    Bitmap resisizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapOrg, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, true);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(resisizedBitmap);
```

With this image scaler the drawing (measured with hierarchy viewer) only takes up 6ms. Both ways get the same result except the drawing speed is way lower on my image scaler. Anyone has an idea why these two things differ so much in drawing speed?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion having two bitmaps in memory in the same time is what is causing the sluggish behaviour.

```
Bitmap bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.image);
//other code ommited
Bitmap resisizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapOrg, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, true);
```

A simpler function like below taken from android developer site will help to decode the bitmap without copying it:

```
public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId,
    int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

// First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

// Calculate inSampleSize
options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

// Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
}
```

Comment: I think you didn't fully understood my question. My function isn't sluggish, however when I use only XML to set my image with the correct properties, the image drawing speed is taking almost 10 times as long as my own implemented image scaler. I don't get why this is happening as I shouldnt have to make an image scaler for my static images inside my viewpager.